# transparent widget in QT

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qwidget

I want to draw a circle on a widget and within the circle background screen should be visible i.e. just border/circumference of circle should be visible on the widget.
Rest of the widget should be transparent.
I have tried :
1) `setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")`
2) `setAttribute( Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true );`
3) `Overriding paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);`

All of the above methode didn't work. and setAutoFillBackground() is false.
I am new to Qt and above solution I just found on google.
Please Help.

Comment: I've read some where that, this feature works only on the systems that support alpha channel drawing for windows!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`QWidget::setMask`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setMask) function, if used on the window, will have that affect.  See also the [shaped clock example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-shapedclock.html) (also referenced from the `setMask` documentation).

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job :D

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui/QPushButton>
#include <QtGui/QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *win=new QMainWindow(0);
    win->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground,true);
    win->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```